# How toload shared html into page without server?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to share a navbar across multiple pages.

Normally you'd do this using jQuery's `.load()` function or some other method requiring a web server but as shown in the example below it is also possible without a web server. However using this method for some reason the contents of `shared.html` gets wrapped in a body which alters the layout. Is there another way to load html pages without a server.

```
<div id="navbar">
</div>

<script>
    function load(){
        document.getElementById("navbar").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="shared.html" ></object>';
    }
    load();
</script>

//contents of shared.html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      ...
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried both ways (http://plnkr.co/edit/Sbh6P7mFihd8L0GzRyrc?p=preview). The issue with object is that it always wraps its content in a completely new document (you can see this if you view it in the developer console). I think the only way to insert this html without a body is to use something like $.load. This should be fine because shared.html has to reside somewhere, there is little difference whether we get shared.html using ajax or using object data.

Comment: there is ajax requires a server and object data doesnt

Comment: Actually, AJAX doesn't require a server for static files- try it! (by server I guess you mean server-side language like php)

Comment: i get an error if i use jquery.load(); XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Paul%20Boon/Documents/HobbySite/shared.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. I dont get this error if i put this on a server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a form that has only the code you need from the shared.html and then include it using php.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      <?php include("shared.html") ?>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i'm trying to do this without a server